# Haskell error - 'parse error on input `->'

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

I am trying to declare a function in Haskell GHCi as

`fact :: Int -> Int`

But I am getting this error - **error:** *parse error on input `->'*

I do not understand why this is happening. Can anyone please explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: I get "error: Variable not in scope: fact :: Int -> Int" (AFAIK, you can't "forward-declare" a type in ghci). Which version are you using, and is that all your input?

Comment: @Megha  That would work with the compiler, but with GHCi the syntax has to be subtly different. This however works with GHCi v8.2.2: `let { fact :: Int -> Int ; fact 0 = 1 ; fact n = n * fact (n-1)  }`

Answer (score 5):

First off, it looks like you're using a pretty old version of GHC. In newer versions, the GHCi syntax has been relaxed a bit.

But still: what you type in GHCi does *not* have the same rules as what you write in a Haskell source file. Specifically, the GHCi prompt is essentially an IO monad chain evaluator, the reason being that you can write stuff like

```
Prelude> putStrLn "Hello"
Hello
```

or

```
Prelude> readFile "test.txt" 
"fubar\nbaz"
```

and actually have it *execute right there*. By contrast, in a Haskell source file, you only *declare bindings*, and these can then be invoked in the `main` action or a GHCi session.

But in this case, you want to declare a binding within GHCi itself. You *can* do that too, but it's a bit awkward, basically you need to start with `let` and then squeeze everything in a single line:

```
Prelude> let fact :: Int -> Int; fact n = product [1..n]
```

*Actually*, newer GHCi version allow you to omit the `let`, and you can have multiple-line definitions by using a special bracket syntax:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fact :: Int -> Int
Prelude| fact n = product [1..n]
Prelude| :}
```

but I would recommend against this. If you actually have some bigger definitions, better put them in a proper Haskell source and *load* that into GHCi.